# How would I accomplish this using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables in my database that look like so:

```
clients
+-------------+
| id   | sms  |
|------+------|
| 1    | 0    |
| 2    | 1    |
| 3    | 1    |
| 4    | 1    |
+------+------+

clients_lists_relationships
+----------------------+
| listid   | clientid  |
|----------+-----------|
| 1        | 1         |
| 1        | 2         |
| 2        | 1         |
| 3        | 1         |
+----------+-----------+
```

Now what I'm trying to do is get a list of clients who are in a bunch of lists. I do that like so:

```sql
SELECT c.id, 
       l.* 
FROM   clients AS c, 
       clients_lists_relationships AS l 
WHERE  c.id = l.clientid 
       AND c.sms = '1' 
       AND ( l.listid = '1' 
              OR l.listid = '2' );
```

This does give me a list of the clients that I need. But because a client can be in more than one list I get the same client more than once. How would I limit this to only one row for each client no matter how many lists they are in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT c.id, 
       l.listid
FROM clients c
INNER JOIN clients_lists_relationships l
ON c.id = l.clientid
WHERE  c.sms = 1
       AND l.listid IN (1,2)
GROUP BY c.id
```

Note that by doing this you lose information on which lists the client was a member of. This means that you should probably not select anything from `client_lists_relationships` as this information is either redundant (`clientid`) or incomplete (`listid`).

Answer (score 3):

If you just need any client that is in a list, you can just query the relationship table:

```
SELECT DSITINCT(clientid) FROM clients_lists_relationships
```

You can also use that distinct on your combined query, but be aware that the "listid" you'll get is just one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all take a look at [MySQL:: JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) It's much better than the WHERE statements you use now.

I think you are looking for GROUP BY.

In total, the query look like:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    l.* 
FROM   
    clients AS c
INNER JOIN
    clients_lists_relationships AS l
    ON
        l.clientid = c.id 
    AND
        c.sms = '1' 
    AND
        ( l.listid = '1' 
        OR l.listid = '2' );
GROUP BY
    c.id
```

Comment: DOH! how did I not think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To return just the clients participating in more than 1 list you may want to consider using the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT c.id
  FROM Clients c
 INNER JOIN Client_Lists_Relationships l
         ON l.clientid = c.id
 WHERE c.sms = 1
HAVING COUNT(L.listid) > 1
GROUP BY c.id
```